# Using variables within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a problem I cant seem to understand. I'm trying to use the variables tId and datatype (provided in the autoRefresh_div function) in the TimeUrl string but it doesnt seem to work. I've tried:

```
const TimeUrl = "./trips_status.php?tid=" + tId + "&datatype=Type";
```

But that didn't work. Tid comes back as undefined. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? My knowledge of query and javascript is limited so any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
function autoRefresh_div(tId, datatype) {
const TimeUrl = "./trips_status.php?tid=" + tId + "&datatype=Type";
$.get(TimeUrl, function(data) {
    setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 1000);
    string = data;
    if(string >= 0 && string <= 100){
    document.getElementById("triptrop").style.width = string + "%";
    document.getElementById("percentagetext").innerHTML = string + "%";
}
}, "html");

}

autoRefresh_div("199", "type");
</script>
<div id="triptrop" style="width: 0px; background: #dcdcdc; color: #000000"><span id="percentagetext">hi</span></div>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? Are you getting an error in the console or is the get call returning but not with the data you expect?

Comment: The " + tId + " text shows up instead of the data. It's just taking the variable as text instead of treating it like a variable.

Comment: Mmm… not if you wrote it like that. Can you show that version of the code instead of the `tid=199` one? The full thing, exactly the way you ran it.

Comment: Updated the code on my first post.

Comment: Where did you see the wrong value show up? In the network inspector or something? `setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 1000);` isn’t going to work because it calls the function without arguments the next time around, but that will make it show `tid=undefined`, not `tid=" + tId + "`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to convert part of the string in valid Javascript variables?

Comment: That page I'm loading is suppose to come back with a number depending on what the tid is. If I enter the number manually in the url it replaces the divs with data correctly. If I try to get it to pass the number from where I call the function it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes I'm using the inspector to see what's wrong and yes its undefined.

Comment: Well, I am testing right now in my Chromium 79 console and your code works as expected

Comment: Okay, so it’s undefined, not what you said before. `setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 1000, tId, datatype);`, because `setTimeout` is just going to call your function with no arguments unless you ask it to do otherwise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Yeah sorry I was playing around with it so much I remembered the wrong outcome. Thanks and lemme give this a try!

Comment: That was it!! Thanks alot! One other question. How would I attached tid to 
    document.getElementById("triptrop") so it reads triptrop_199?

Comment: `"triptrop"` is a string, like `"./trips_status.php?tid="`.

Comment: Gotcha, so + tId at the end after the quote should do the trick? Thanks for all the help and patience! Promise I'm trying to learn something for the time taken to show me.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) does what you think it does. I say that because it doesn't accept arguments the way you're supplying them.

Comment: It seems to get the result I want. Do you know of alternatives I could use or maybe a resource I could read that shows me what your talking about.

Comment: @NathanHawks: You’re looking at the wrong documentation. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is the string, I would suggest you to try one of the methods below.

```
const TimeUrl = "./trips_status.php?tid= " + tId+ "&datatype="+datatype;
```

Or

```
const TimeUrl = "./trips_status.php?tid= ".concat(tId, "&datatype=",datatype);
```

Add some alert to your code, to verify where you might lose the values (or if it breaks for other reasons).